# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action<mathstester.Program.OperationQuestionScore>' to 'mathstester.Program.OperationQuestionScore'

Tags: c#, types, error-handling

I made a C# console math project where the user answers addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power or square-root questions based on the difficulty they choose!

Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace mathstester
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum UserDifficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Normal,
            Hard
        }

        public enum MathOperation
        {
            Addition = 1,
            Subtraction = 2,
            Multiplication = 3,
            Division = 4,
            Power = 5,
            SquareRoot = 6
        }
        public static (int operationMin, int operationMax) GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {

            switch (userDifficulty)
            {
                case UserDifficulty.Easy:
                    return (1, 4);
                case UserDifficulty.Normal:
                    return (1, 5);
                case UserDifficulty.Hard:
                    return (3, 7);
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public class OperationQuestionScore
        {
            public int AdditionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int AdditionScore { get; set; }
            public int SubtractionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int SubtractionScore { get; set; }
            public int MultiplicationQuestion { get; set; }
            public int MultiplicationScore { get; set; }
            public int DivisionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int DivisionScore { get; set; }
            public int PowerQuestion { get; set; }
            public int PowerScore { get; set; }
            public int SquareRootQuestion { get; set; }
            public int SquareRootScore { get; set; }

            public static (OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) Scores(MathOperation mathOperation)
            {
                Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationQuestion;
                Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationScore;
                switch (mathOperation)
                {
                    case MathOperation.Addition:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.AdditionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.AdditionScore++;
                    case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SubtractionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SubtractionScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.MultiplicationQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.MultiplicationScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Division:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.DivisionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.DivisionScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Power:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.PowerQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.PowerScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SquareRootQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SquareRootScore++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore);
            }
        }

        public static OperationQuestionScore Score()
        {
            return new OperationQuestionScore();
        }

        public static (string message, double correctAnswer) GetMathsEquation(MathOperation mathOperation, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {
            int number1;
            int number2;
            Random randomNumber = new Random();

            switch (mathOperation)
            {
                case MathOperation.Addition:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} + {number2}", number1 + number2);
                case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} - {number2}", number1 - number2);
                case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                    number1 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? randomNumber.Next(13) : randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? randomNumber.Next(13) : randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} * {number2}", number1 * number2);
                case MathOperation.Division:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(10000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} / {number2}", number1 / (double)number2);
                case MathOperation.Power:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(13);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(5);
                    return ($"{number1} ^ {number2}", Math.Pow(number1, number2));
                case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"√{number1}", Math.Sqrt(number1));
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public static (int, OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {
            int totalScore = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(userDifficulty);
            var score = Score();
            var question = Score();
            var (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore) = Scores();
            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
            {
                int mathRandomOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
                MathOperation mathOperation = (MathOperation)mathRandomOperation;
                var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
                if (mathRandomOperation == 4 || mathRandomOperation == 6)
                {
                    Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
                }
                double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                    incrementOperationQuestion(question);
                    incrementOperationScore(score);
                    totalScore++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    incrementOperationQuestion(question);
                }
                numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
            }
            return (totalScore, score, question);
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, UserDifficulty> difficultyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, UserDifficulty>();
            difficultyDictionary.Add("E", UserDifficulty.Easy);
            difficultyDictionary.Add("N", UserDifficulty.Normal);
            difficultyDictionary.Add("H", UserDifficulty.Hard);

            string userInputDifficulty = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
                userInputDifficulty = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (userInputDifficulty != "E" && userInputDifficulty != "N" && userInputDifficulty != "H");

            UserDifficulty userDifficulty = difficultyDictionary[userInputDifficulty];

            int numberOfQuestions = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
            } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

            var (totalScore, score, question) = RunTest(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty);
            Console.WriteLine($"Total score: {totalScore} of {numberOfQuestions}");

            if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {question.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {question.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Normal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {question.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {question.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {question.DivisionQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Hard)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Multipication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {question.DivisionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Power score: {score.PowerScore} of {question.PowerQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Squareroot score: {score.SquareRootScore} of {question.SquareRootQuestion}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where my problem is:

```
public static (OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) Scores(MathOperation mathOperation)
            {
                Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationQuestion;
                Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationScore;
                switch (mathOperation)
                {
                    case MathOperation.Addition:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.AdditionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.AdditionScore++;
                    case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SubtractionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SubtractionScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.MultiplicationQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.MultiplicationScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Division:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.DivisionQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.DivisionScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.Power:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.PowerQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.PowerScore++;
                        break;
                    case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                        incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SquareRootQuestion++;
                        incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SquareRootScore++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore);
            }
```

In my function "Score" I have an error with the `return (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore);`.

The error says

```
1. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action<mathstester.Program.OperationQuestionScore>'
    to 'mathstester.Program.OperationQuestionScore'

2. Use of unassigned local variable 'incerementOperationScore'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What type is `OperationQuestionScore`? Why are you trying to assign a lambda expression to it?

Comment: Show definition of `OperationQuestionScore` please

Comment: Also, if you need a switch statement to increment variables, you've already painted yourself into a corner. Why not a dictionary, keyed on `MathOperation`?

Comment: `OperationQuestionScore` is a class.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can you show me how I would do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action' to
>   'mathstester.Program.OperationQuestionScore'

This error occurs because method `Scores` is declared to return a tuple of type `(OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore)` but it actually returns a tuple of type `(Action<OperationQuestionScore>, Action<OperationQuestionScore>)`. To fix this problem you should change the return type of the method `Scores`:

```
public static (Action<OperationQuestionScore>, Action<OperationQuestionScore>) Scores(MathOperation mathOperation)
```

---

> Use of unassigned local variable 'incerementOperationScore'

Such error indicates that there is a usage of a variable that was not assigned to a value. In your case compiler tells that there is a possibility of using unassigned variable `incerementOperationScore`. It can occur if an argument `mathOperation` does not match any of the switch cases, and empty `default` case does not assign a value to `incerementOperationScore`. At the moment all possible `mathOperation` values are handled by switch statement and it is implied that `default` branch will never execute. But in future you could add a new math operation and forget to add it to this switch statement. To prevent such errors compiler forces us to handle all possible case values (even if we'll add them in future).

To fix this problem you should either throw an exception in the `default` case:

```
default:
    throw new System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException("mathOperation", (int) mathOperation, typeof(MathOperation));
```

or handle one of the `MathOperation` values in the `default` case:

```
default: // For example, use default branch instead of MathOperation.SquareRoot branch.
    incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SquareRootQuestion++;
    incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SquareRootScore++;
    break;
```

Personally I prefer to throw an exception. It helps to handle situations when you forget to add a new case branch for newly added enum value.

---

There is also another error in the `Scores` method. `break` keyword is missed in the first case branch.

---

Here is complete `Scores` method with fixed errors:

```
public static (Action<OperationQuestionScore>, Action<OperationQuestionScore>) Scores(MathOperation mathOperation)
{
    Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationQuestion;
    Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementOperationScore;
    switch (mathOperation)
    {
       case MathOperation.Addition:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.AdditionQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.AdditionScore++;
          break;
       case MathOperation.Subtraction:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SubtractionQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SubtractionScore++;
          break;
       case MathOperation.Multiplication:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.MultiplicationQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.MultiplicationScore++;
          break;
       case MathOperation.Division:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.DivisionQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.DivisionScore++;
          break;
       case MathOperation.Power:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.PowerQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.PowerScore++;
          break;
       case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
          incrementOperationQuestion = incrementquestion => incrementquestion.SquareRootQuestion++;
          incrementOperationScore = incrementscore => incrementscore.SquareRootScore++;
          break;
       default:
          throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("mathOperation", (int) mathOperation, typeof(MathOperation));
    }
    return (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore);
}
```

---

@crazydanyal1414 asked in the comment:

> But how would I define the "Scores" function into "RunTest"?

A minor change to the method `RunTest` is needed. Here is changed method `RunTest`. I described made changes in the comments:

```
public static (int, OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
{
    int totalScore = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(userDifficulty);
    var score = Score();
    var question = Score();

    // Move this line into the while loop.
    //var (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore) = Scores();

    while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
    {
        int mathRandomOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
        MathOperation mathOperation = (MathOperation)mathRandomOperation;
        var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
        if (mathRandomOperation == 4 || mathRandomOperation == 6)
        {
           Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
        }
        else
        {
           Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
        }

        // Here is moved line.
        // Method Scores must be invoked using static method invocation
        // syntax, and a parameter mathOperation must be passed into it.
        var (incrementOperationQuestion, incrementOperationScore) = OperationQuestionScore.Scores(mathOperation);

        double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
           incrementOperationQuestion(question);
           incrementOperationScore(score);
           totalScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
           incrementOperationQuestion(question);
        }
        numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
     }
     return (totalScore, score, question);
}
```